# How to make if else condition in python 2d array

Tags: python

I have a 2d array with shape(3,6), then i want to create a condition to check a value of each array.
my data arry is as follows :

> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
> 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
> [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])

if in an array there are numbers < 10 then the value will be 0

the result I expected

> array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
> 0,  0,  0, 10, 11, 12],
> [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])

the code i created is like this, but why can't it work as i expected

```
FCDataNew = []

a = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
     [7,8,9,10,11,12], 
     [13,14,15,16,17,18]
     ]

a = np.array(a)

c = 0
c = np.array(c)

for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i].all()<10:
    FCDataNew.append(c)
  else:
    FCDataNew.append(a[i])

FCDataNew = np.array(FCDataNew)
FCDataNew
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the array in place, use boolean indexing:

```
FCDataNew = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                      [7,8,9,10,11,12],
                      [13,14,15,16,17,18],
                     ])

FCDataNew[FCDataNew<10] = 0
```

For a copy:

```
out = np.where(FCDataNew<10, 0, FCDataNew)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: FCDataNew = []

a = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
     [7,8,9,10,11,12], 
     [13,14,15,16,17,18]
     ]

a = np.array(a)

c = 0
c = np.array(c)

for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i].all()<10:
    FCDataNew.append(c)
  else:
    FCDataNew.append(a[i])


FCDataNew = np.array(FCDataNew)

out = np.where(FCDataNew<10, 0, FCDataNew)

Comment: Is it like this?

Comment: No, just what I wrote in the answer, no need for a loop

Comment: but how if in the case I have negative value?

Comment: array([[ -8,  -2,  3,  4,  -1,  2],
       [ 7,  -1,  -2, -1, 10, -3],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])

Comment: if the data such above then I want to make condition if < 0 will be 0 then else >0 will be 1

Comment: how should it behave? it should work fine as it is. Or do you want to consider the absolute value?

Comment: For 0 if >0 else 1, use `out = (FCDataNew>0).astype(int)` or `out = np.where(FCDataNew>0, 1, 0)`

Comment: but if I use out = np.where(FCDataNew>0, 1,0) the data will wrong

Comment: Then I didn't undestand what you want, please edit the question and make an effort to explain clearly (logic + expected output)

Comment: if the data such this array([[ -8, -2, 3, 4, 1, 2], [ 7, -1, -2, -1, 10, -3], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]) , then my expected data is array([[ 0, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2], [ 1, -1, -2, -1, 1, -3], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])  so if there are more positive negative values then fcDataNew>0= 0, else fcDataNew<0= 1

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `arr[arr < 10] = 0`